# Как исполнить bash комманду используя gcc?

Tags: c, bash, взлом

Необходимо вызвать команду
`/challenge/embryoio_level42|cat`
при помощи приложения написанного на языке C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void pwncollege(void);

void main()
{
   pwncollege();
}
void pwncollege()
{
char *args[] = {"/challenge/embryoio_level60",NULL};
if(fork()==0)
execve(args[0],args,NULL);
wait(NULL);
}
```

Как правильно интегрировать pipline в данный код,если нужно использовать exec?

Comment: `system("/challenge/embryoio_level42 | cat");`

Comment: К сожалению надо через exec

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-fork-exec/

Comment: ¿Почему "надо"? Если это какое-то учебное задание, то приводите его толком.

Comment: Требование к челленджу по ссылке https://gist.github.com/vasilukwolf/e6106193e0a6e79a721c1536420922bc и я не понимаю, как исполнить дублированные команды

Comment: Тогда тут надо в `execve` запускать bash, и передавать ему команду посредством аргумента `-c`. И результат `fork` необходимо сохранять чтобы потом использовать его для `waitpid`